# show values for multiple ids in a column in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table called register, where I store user's data like username,birth-date,language.
there I offer them to add multiple languages. and I store that languages as id in database.
I have separate table for language too.

now I want to create a view that fetch all data with multiple select language.

```
CREATE TABLE `register` (
 `index_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `password` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
 `m_status` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `occupation` int(5) NOT NULL,
 `m_tongue` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`index_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=621 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Please consider using a junction table to store the language to user relation. It's almost never a good idea to store multiple values in a column.

Comment: thanks, but if you help me on this then it will be grateful

Comment: With this table layout you could do something in the line `FROM register INNER JOIN languages ON FIND_IN_SET(languages.id, register.m_tongue)`. But you should really consider changing your database design.